# Python: adding value from list of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

below is my list of lists;

```
db_rows = [('a','b','c',4),
           ('a','s','f',6),
           ('a','c','d',6),
           ('a','b','f',2),
           ('a','b','c',6),
           ('a','b','f',8),
           ('a','s','f',6),
           ('a','b','f',7),
           ('a','s','f',5),
           ('a','b','f',2)]
```

if first three values are same in the inner list then I need to add 4th value to create new list

I need result list like this:

```
final_list = [('a','b','c',10),
              ('a','s','f',17),
              ('a','c','d',6),
              ('a','b','f',19)]
```

I have tried the below script (not working):

```
final_list = []
for row in db_rows:
    temp_flag=False
    temp_list = []
    val = 0
    for ref_row in db_rows:
        if row != ref_row:
            if row[0]==ref_row[0] and row[1]==ref_row[1] and row[2]==ref_row[2]:
                val = val + ref_row[3]
                temp_flag=True
    temp_list=(row[0],row[1],row[2],val)
    if temp_flag==False:
        temp_list=row
    final_list.append(temp_list)
```

please advice me.

Comment: Please share your attempt to achieve this result.

Comment: Try using a dictionary with the first three values as the key.

Comment: Please correct the desired output. It should be `('a','c','d',6)` instead of `('a','b','d',6)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a dictionary as  Dov Grobgeld commented, then convert the dictionary back to the list.

```
from collections import defaultdict

db_rows = [('a','b','c',4),
           ('a','s','f',6),
           ('a','c','d',6),
           ('a','b','f',2),
           ('a','b','c',6),
           ('a','b','f',8),
           ('a','s','f',6),
           ('a','b','f',7),
           ('a','s','f',5),
           ('a','b','f',2)]

sums = defaultdict(int)
for row in db_rows:
    sums[row[:3]] += row[3]

final_list = [key + (value,) for key, value in sums.iteritems()]
```

Printing `final_list` outputs:

```
[('a', 'b', 'c', 10), ('a', 's', 'f', 17), ('a', 'b', 'f', 19), ('a', 'c', 'd', 6)]
```

See [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict
db_rows = [('a','b','c',4),
           ('a','s','f',6),
           ('a','c','d',6),
           ('a','b','f',2),
           ('a','b','c',6),
           ('a','b','f',8),
           ('a','s','f',6),
           ('a','b','f',7),
           ('a','s','f',5),
           ('a','b','f',2)]

d = defaultdict(int)


for ele in db_rows:
    d[ele[:-1]] += ele[-1]

print([(k +(v,)) for k,v in d.items()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I am using `OrderedDict` to preserve the order in which first three values are found.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

db_rows = [('a','b','c',4),
           ('a','s','f',6),
           ('a','c','d',6),
           ('a','b','f',2),
           ('a','b','c',6),
           ('a','b','f',8),
           ('a','s','f',6),
           ('a','b','f',7),
           ('a','s','f',5),
           ('a','b','f',2)]

temp_dict = OrderedDict()

for x in db_rows:
    temp_dict[x[:3]] = temp_dict.get(x[:3], 0) + x[3]

final_list =  [k +(v,) for k,v in temp_dict.iteritems()]
```

We can now check value of `final_list` which gives the desired result in the order as mentioned above.

```
final_list
[('a', 'b', 'c', 10),
 ('a', 's', 'f', 17),
 ('a', 'c', 'd', 6),
 ('a', 'b', 'f', 19)]
```